# Graph Theory Problem about connectedness

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Problem:

> Let $G$ be a graph and $d(u)+d(v)+d(w)\geq(n-1)$ where $u$, $v$ and $w$ are three non adjacent vertex to each other, then prove that $G$ is a connected graph.

Approach:

$u$, $v$ and $w$ are not adjacent to each other so $d(u)\leq(n-3),$
$d(v)\leq(n-3)$, $d(w)\leq(n-3)$ 
Therefore we can say that $(n-1)\leq d(u)+d(v)+d(w)\leq 3(n-3)$. Then what??
I don't know..

Comment: What about a simple graph on four vertices consisting of a triangle and an isolated vertex?  This graph is not connected, but satisfies the condition.

Comment: @Batominovski Edit: there's no way to pick three vertices with no two adjacent if there's only one isolated vertex. Maybe this almost-counterexample can be fixed?

Comment: @GuidoA.  The condition does not state that three vertices can be picked.  I will state this in terms of logic: $\forall x\in\emptyset\,[P(x)]$ is a true statement no matter what $P(x)$ is.  So, if you cannot find three nonadjacent vertices in a graph, this graph satisfies the required condition.

Comment: The condition surely does not allow one to pick vertices, but as I understood it, it does assume that there are three vertices pairwise non adjacent with their degrees summing at least $(n-1)$, thus making the statement vacuously true for graphs with no three pairwise non adjacent vertices. Am I misunderstanding what's being asked?

Comment: @GuidoA.  Well, the OP's statement can be translated as follows: "for all graph $G$, if [for all vertices $u,v,w$ of $G$, if $u,v,w$ are nonadjacent, then $\deg(u)+\deg(v)+\deg(w)\geq n-1$], then $G$ is connected."  This allows the case without three nonadjacent vertices.  But if you are dead on having a counterexample with three nonadjacent vertices, just consider a graph on seven vertices with a triangle and a square which are disjoint.

Comment: @Batominovski Got it. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This is a necessary condition but no sufficient  @Guido A

Comment: This could also be read with an existential quantifier instead of a universal quantifier, but that also has a counterexample: a hexagon plus an isolated point. Thus I assume that the desired statement must be some modification of the version with the universal quantifier.

Comment: Even if you assume a universal quantifier and that there exists a triple of pairwise nonadjacent vertices the statement is false, take $K_4$ disjoint union a square then take one vertex of $K_4$ and the two opposite vertices of the square. These have total degree $2+2+3=7 = 8-1$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a version of the statement that claims that $G$ is connected that is true (see the counterexamples in the comments on the question). However, one can prove that if $G$ satisfies the property that for all triples of pairwise nonadjacent vertices $u,v,w$, $d(u)+d(v)+d(w)\ge n-2$, then $G$ has at most 2 connected components.

**Proof:**

If $G$ is connected then we are done, so suppose $x$ and $y$ are two vertices of $G$ with no path between them. Certainly $x$ and $y$ must be nonadjacent. Further if $N(x)\cap N(y)\ne \varnothing$, then there is some vertex $z$ adjacent to both $x$ and $y$, which would imply that $xzy$ is a path from $x$ to $y$. Hence we also know that $N(x)\cap N(y)=\varnothing$.

Now for every other vertex $z$ of $G$ either $z$ is adjacent to $x$, adjacent to $y$, or adjacent to neither. If $z$ is adjacent to neither $x$ nor $y$, then we know that $d(x)+d(y)+d(z) \ge n-2$. Since $x,y,z$ are pairwise nonadjacent, $N(x)\cup N(y)\cup N(z) \subseteq V\setminus \{x,y,z\}$. Thus by pigeonhole, there is at least one vertex that is in at least two of the sets $N(x)$, $N(y)$, or $N(z)$. Since $N(x)$ and $N(y)$ are disjoint, this implies that $z$ shares a neighbor with at least one of $x$ or $y$. Thus all vertices of $G$ lie in the connected component of either $x$ or $y$.